# Centroid of a set of points in Python

Tags: python, function, points, centroid

I have a set of coordinates (x,y) and im trying to write a function that generates the centroid of them, so far I keep getting errors, here is the code I have so far:

```
def get_centroid(x,y):
    centroid = (sum(x)/len(x),sum(y)/len(y))


x=[3,1,5,7,4,-2]
y=[0,-3,-3,1,5,2]
```

thank you for any help or suggestions.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Change `centroid = ...` to `return ...`. You are neither returning nor printing.

Comment: "I get errors" is not a good description. Please always copy and paste the _exact_ error message. That is much more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach will work, but just remember to `return` your result and be careful of dividing by zero with empty lists.